# How to enable tag immutability in quay.io?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, quay.io, dip

Elastic Container Registry (ECR) for example supports Tag Immutability (TI). TI implies that docker tags cannot be overwritten if they exist in a docker-registry.

The settings of the organization and the ones from a repository were inspected, but no TI setting was found.

**Questions**

- Does quay support TI?
- If true, how to enable it
- If false, how do you or does your organization prevent that tag overwrite takes place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance, it seems that tag immutability is not a feature provided by Quay. You can enable "Trust and Signing" in the "settings" of the repo:

> Please note that this will not prevent users from overwriting signed tags without updating signatures. This means that:
>
> - Any tag operations in the UI or client can cause inconsistency
> - Builds should not push to signed tags
>
> We recommend you maintain a strict separation between signed and unsigned tags to avoid any issues with garbage collection.

So, you can sign tags, but you can't prevent them from being updated.